# how to load vim8 optional packages in vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system, packages, vim8

I am trying to load my optional language packages based on filetype.
I am using vim8 native package feature.

In vim I can load them with `:packadd vim-javascript`. However, I read in `:help packadd` - (emphasis mine)

> **[`:pa[ckadd][!] {name}`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Apackadd)**
>
> Search for an optional plugin directory in `'packpath'` and source any plugin files found.  The directory must match: `pack/*/opt/{name}`
>
> The directory is added to `'runtimepath'` if it wasn't there yet. If the directory `pack/*/opt/{name}/after` exists it is added at the end of `'runtimepath'`.
>
> If loading packages from `pack/*/start` was skipped, then this directory is searched first: `pack/*/start/{name}`
>
> Note that `{name}` is the directory name, not the name of the `.vim` file.  All the files matching the pattern `pack/*/opt/{name}/plugin/**/*.vim` will be sourced.  This allows for using subdirectories below `plugin`, just like with plugins in `'runtimepath'`.
>
> **If the filetype detection was not enabled yet (this is usually done with a `syntax enable` or `filetype on` command in your `.vimrc` file), this will also look for `{name}/ftdetect/*.vim` files.**
>
> **When the optional `!` is added no plugin files or ftdetect scripts are loaded, only the matching directories are added to `'runtimepath'`.  This is useful in your `.vimrc`.  The plugins will then be loaded during initialization, see [|load-plugins|](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#load-plugins).**
>
> Also see [|pack-add|](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#pack-add). {only available when compiled with `+eval`}

So I try to write something in my vimrc but it doesn't work.

```
autocmd! FileType javascript packadd vim-javascript
" Or
autocmd FileType javascript packadd! vim-javascript
```

I found this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/7doeit/using_vim_8_package_loader_tipguide/) but as I mentioned, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> how to load vim8 optional packages in vimrc?

The way to load vim8 optional packages in your vimrc is to use the `:packadd!` command, which will add them to your `'runtimepath'`, which will make the `opt` plugins load together with the ones in `start`.

In your particular case:

```
packadd! vim-javascript
```

The examples you give hint that what you're actually trying to do is load a vim8 optional package *from an autocmd*, which is a slightly different question.

The reason they don't work is most likely because you're already processing a `FileType` event at that point, and the plugin you're loading will register new `autocmd`s for that same event, but those will most probably not be triggered for that same event you're already handling. Maybe you could hack something together using `doautocmd` to process those commands again, but I really don't think that would be worth it.

The problem here is that **you're trying to optimize something which is not a performance problem**, or at least you haven't found it to be one.

Like most well written plug-ins, vim-javascript won't really load much of anything at the time it's loaded and the bulk of it will only get loaded once you start to actually use it (in this case, once you start editing JavaScript sources.)

Since vim-javascript (like most language plug-ins) doesn't carry any `plugin/*.vim` files, the only code that will get loaded at startup is [`ftdetect/javascript.vim`](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript/blob/master/ftdetect/javascript.vim), which has only 11 lines of Vimscript, should load really quickly and **it's something you actually want loaded at startup**, since it contains interesting bits of FileType detection (such as looking for a `node` shebang) that you'd be otherwise missing.

The [`:help pack-add`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#pack-add) page has some interesting comments on the rationale for `opt` and what should be stored there:

> **Where to put what**
>
> [...]
>
> Filetype plugins should go under `pack/*/start`, so that they are always found.  Unless you have more than one plugin for a file type and want to select which one to load with `:packadd`.  E.g. depending on the compiler
>   version:
>
> ```
> if foo_compiler_version > 34
>     packadd foo_new
> else
>     packadd foo_old
> endif
> ```

In other words, the *intent* of having filetype plug-ins under `opt` is not to add the plug-in on demand. It is to add the plug-in conditionally, based on presence of some feature in your system which can be dynamically detected from your `.vimrc`. For instance, you might want to detect whether a `node` binary exists or if `eslint` is present or similar, and only enable vim-javascript in those cases.

The problem of loading a plug-in's scripts on demand had been already solved, that's by using `autoload` and `ftplugin`. So the cost of adding it unconditionally is quite low, almost insignificant, at Vim startup. Definitely not a reason to try to add it from an `autocmd`.